# Error in Expression Engine Embed

Tags: expressionengine

I have a site I'm working on at the moment, in which I have a sidebar displaying the 10 most recent posts (titles as links). I'm calling this in with the Embed function.

Though when I am looking on the individual post itself, the list only displays the post title that I'm on.

My embedded code calls all 10 of the recent posts in a exp:channels entry normal way.

Is there something I've done wrong? Below is the code for the main blog page:

```
       {embed="embeds/html_header"}
       <!-- content -->
       {embed="embeds/html_blog_top"}

       <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
       {embed="embeds/html_blog_sidebar"}
       {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1"}
       <div class="span8">

    <article>

        <header class="postHeader">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3 postDate">{entry_date format="%d"}<span>{entry_date format="%F"}</span></div>
                <div class="span9 postPic">
                        <div class="imgWrapper">
                            {blog_image}
                        </div>
                     </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="span6 offset2">
                <h2>{title}</h2>
                <p>{full_entry}</p>
                <p><span class='st_sharethis' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
                            <span class='st_facebook' displayText='Facebook'></span>
                    <span class='st_twitter' displayText='Tweet'></span>
                </p>
                </section>

        </div>
    </article>

       </div>
       {/exp:channel:entries} 
       </div>
       </div>
       </section>


       <!-- footer -->
       {embed="embeds/html_footer"}
```

This is the sidebar embed:

```
    <aside class="span4" style="float:right;">
    <section class="widget search clearfix">
    <h3>news</h3>
    <p>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="10" orderby="date"}
    <a href="{url_title_path='blog/post'}">{title}</a><br>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </p>
    </section>
    <section class="widget">
    <h3>Archives</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>
    {exp:channel:month_links channel="blog"}
    <a href="{path='blog'}">{month} {year}</a><br>
    {/exp:channel:month_links}
    </li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    </aside>
```

Its just the bit with the news section that I can't seem to get as a full list on the individual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dynamic="no" to your embed entries loop and you should be good.

Also, if you want answers on ExpressionEngine questions more quickly, try posting to [expressionengine.stackexchange.com](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)